# Running an m-file script from LabView

Tags: matlab, labview

I was wondering if anyone knew how to run an m script from LabView. I know how to run functions, which is through eval in the Matlab script box, but cant seem to get the m script to launch with variables input into the box.

Comment: What error (if any) are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still going to use the [Mathscript Node](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361E-01/gmath/mathscript_node/).

I don't have LabVIEW in front of me, but it seems it's as simple as naming the input *exactly* the same as the variables in your script. See `A` and `n` in the example in the above link. The same goes for outputs.

---

**EDIT:**  Here is a great tutorial provided by Phil Brooks in the comments: [Working with .m File Scripts in NI LabVIEW for Text Based Signal Processing, Analysis, and Math](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/7006)

Comment: @Cenoc So it runs without reporting an error? Have you tried outputting the input data directly? What comes out? Another suggestion would be to create a new VI with minimum components (i.e. Mathscript node and I/O). If it works in that case then you have another error in your other VI.

Comment: The Mathscript Node syntax is **SIMILAR** to Matlab, but functions you have used may not be present or identical.

[Working with .m File Scripts in NI LabVIEW for Text Based Signal Processing, Analysis, and Math](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/7006)